# Weird error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file

Tags: android

The app builds properly without any errors but crashes every time I try to run it. Here is the trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.thevarunshah.swotanalysistool, PID: 18808
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thevarunshah.swotanalysistool/com.thevarunshah.swotanalysistool.HomeScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3336)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3399)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:348)
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2062)
   at com.thevarunshah.swotanalysistool.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:26)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3336) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3399) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:348) 
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2062) 
   at com.thevarunshah.swotanalysistool.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:26) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.initTitle(ActionBarView.java:1211)
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setDisplayOptions(ActionBarView.java:993)
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:399)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3336) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3399) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:348) 
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2062) 
   at com.thevarunshah.swotanalysistool.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:26) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.initTitle(ActionBarView.java:1211) 
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setDisplayOptions(ActionBarView.java:993) 
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:399) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3336) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3399) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:348) 
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2062) 
   at com.thevarunshah.swotanalysistool.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:26) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:327)
   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1094)
    at android.widget.Text
```

Not sure what is causing this error - any help would be appreciated!

Here a few things that could help:

```
HomeScreen.java:26: setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
```

**home_screen.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/homeBG"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.thevarunshah.swotanalysistool.HomeScreen">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/swot_logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/swot" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**HomeScreen.java:**

```
package com.thevarunshah.swotanalysistool;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import com.thevarunshah.swotanalysistool.backend.Database;
import com.thevarunshah.swotanalysistool.backend.SWOTObject;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class HomeScreen extends Activity {

    private Context ctx;
    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 1500;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
        ctx = getApplicationContext();
        Database.setSWOTs(new HashMap<Integer, SWOTObject>());
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput("swot_backup.ser");
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Database.setId(ois.readInt());
            Database.setSWOTs((HashMap<Integer, SWOTObject>)ois.readObject());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            try{
                if(ois != null) ois.close();
                if(fis != null) fis.close();
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                    // Start your app main activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SavedSWOTsScreen.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // close this activity
                    finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post your complete layout xml file.

Comment: @Keshav1234: which layout xml file? the error refers to only the homescreen.xml file which I have already posted.

Comment: Post some java code from where you are inflating.

Comment: @MangeshGhotage: added the java file which the error is referring to.

Comment: Most probably the error happens when you create `SavedSWOTsScreen`, so we need: XML layout file, java file of that Activity, at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your error trace, there's a problem with some color not being properly defined:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
```

So you have to look for a TextView you're inflating (inside an adapter?):

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
```

Without more code / xml these are just guesses.

Also, this could be a problem with your App's theme / styles, as the ActionBar complains when created:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
```

Is this color properly defined? Post here:

```
    android:background="@color/homeBG"
```

Comment: thank you!! it was the app's theme - I was using material but my minSdkVersion was too low (16)... changed it to 21 and it seems to be working.